# ¿Como mostrar un indice en orden en una taba que omite filas?

Tags: php, array

tengo una tabla en la que omito las filas en las que no me aparecen un valor, eso lo he hecho con un contador e ingresando cada fila en una variable string. Si se presenta el valor, el contador aumenta, e imprime la variable con la fila. Si no, simplemente la omite.

El problema es el siguiente, quiero que el indice que es la variable i, aparezca en orden de 1, 2, 3, 4... y asi sucesivamente, pero debido a que va dentro del foreach y algunas filas se eliminan, aparece asi, 1, 29, 58, etc.

```
    <tbody>
    <? $i = 1; ?>
    <? foreach($result as $row){ ?>

    <? $tr = ''; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<tr data-id="'.($row->idVisita).'">'; ?>

    <!--Aqui se imprime el indice que causa problema-->
    <? $tr .= '<td>'.($i++).'</td>';?>
    <? $tr .= '<td class="text-center">'. ($row->fecha). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td class="text-center">'. ($row->tipoUsuario). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td class="text-center">'. ($row->idUsuario). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td>'. ($row->nombreUsuario). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td>'. ($row->cadena). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td>'. ($row->canal). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td>'. ($row->zona). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td>'. ($row->ciudad). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td>'. ($row->provincia). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td>'. ($row->distrito). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td class="text-center">'. ($row->idCliente). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td class="text-center">'. ($row->codTeva). '</td>'; ?>
    <? $tr .= '<td>'. ($row->cliente). '</td>'; ?>

    <?
        //El contador que verifica si cada fila tiene al menos un valor.
        $cont = 0;
    ?>

    <? foreach($productos as $key => $value){

        $cssBackground = 'background-color: #f1f1f1; color: #b9b8b8';
        $td = '-';
        if ( isset($resultados[$row->idVisita][$key]['sugerido']) ){
            if( !empty($resultados[$row->idVisita][$key]['sugerido']) ){
                $cssBackground = '';
                $td = '<strong>'. $resultados[$row->idVisita][$key]['sugerido'].'</strong>';
                //Si pasa la condicion de que una fila tiene al menos un valor, el contador aumenta
                //E imprime en las siguientes lineas, la variable que almacena todo el html.
                $cont++;
            }
        }
    ?>

    <? $tr .= '<td class="text-center" style="'.$cssBackground.'" >'.$td.'</td>';?>
    <?}?>


    <? $tr .= '</tr>';?>

    <!--Si el contador es mayor a 0, la fila no es una fila sin valores, y por lo tanto la imprime-->
    <?if($cont > 0){
        //Aqui se imprime la variable que contiene cada fila por cada recorrido en el foreach.
        echo $tr;
        }
        ?>
    <? } ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias restar cuando no imprimes la fila asi:

```
<?if($cont > 0){
        //Aqui se imprime la variable que contiene cada fila por cada recorrido en el foreach.
        echo $tr;
  } else {
      $i--;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Pero ese contador solo se encarga de verificar si una fila tiene los valores requeridos para ser mostrado. El problema es la variable i que aumenta en cada foreach.

Comment: Ese contador es el que determina si la fila se imprime o no.  Cuando no se imprima, simplemente le restas el valor al contador `$i` en la parte del `else`.

Comment: Si tienes razon. Disculpa por no haber revisado bien.